# CodeIgniter - How to send parameter from api respond to another page in a view

Tags: vue.js, codeigniter

How to send a parameter from api respond to other view page. I was wondering if someone could tell me the correct way to link to another page from within a view.

firstview.php

```
<tbody>
     <tr v-for="(c, index) in contents">
         <td>{{c.uni_ptj_code}}</td>
         <td>{{c.cm_app_level_desc_eng}}</td>
         <td>{{c.uni_prog_desc_eng}}</td>
         <td>{{c.uni_sesi_semester_session_number}}</td>
         <td>{{c.std_type_desc_eng}}</td>
         <td>
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-end flex-shrink-0">
               <a :href="getSpecialRequirementsSetUrl(c.id)" class="btn btn-icon btn-bg- 
               light btn-active-color-primary btn-sm me-1">
              </div>
          </td>
     </tr>
</tbody>
```

vue function

```
getSpecialRequirementsSetUrl(id) {        
    return base_url + 'promotional/special_requirements_set/${id}';
},
```

my route

```
$routes->get('special_requirements_set/(:any)','SpecialRequirementsSet::index/$1');
```

mycontroller

```
public function index($id){

        $data = [
            'title' => 'Special Requirements Set',
            'id' => $id
        ];
        $this->render_module('special_requirements_set', $data);
    }
```

my basecontroller which is the render_module loc

```
public function render_module($view, $data=""){
        $uri = service('uri');
        $modules = $uri->getSegment(1);
        $modules = ucwords($modules);
        $modules_view_location = "../Modules/$modules/Views/";
        $title = $data['title'];
        $array = [
            'title' => $title,
            'view' => $modules_view_location.$view,
            'data' => $data,
            'list_menu' => $this->session->get('list_menu'),
        ];

        if($this->session->logged_in){
            echo view('render/default/main', $array);
        } else {
            echo view('login/main');
        }
        
    }
```

Right now, the link is works and the page can view, but it's like without css file because the page became messy. And i think it's from my render_module funtion. But i don't know the exact problem.